# Ruby on Rails - what is the best practice for accessing Active record Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am really new at rails but i was wondering.

What is the best practice for accessing model column names in rails when doing queries?

like i want to do a order by column called "title" in DESCENDING order. how would i do it (best practice)?

```
MyModel.order(:title.to_s.concat " DESC").all 

MyModel.order("title DESC").all
```

or something else?

From my experience using hardcoded strings always proves the wrong approach in matters such as this mainly because the code becomes impossible to refactor.

in My IDE (i am using RubyMine) it is showing a nice code completition for the colum symbols so i am guessing will be easier to track the use this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion `MyModel.order("title DESC").all` is the better choice here. Readability and complexity of the other choice are bad. Although performance might not be a consideration the other choice also scores bad in this section.

Apart from that, you should never write code by your IDE intellisense ability - your code should be navigable and readable in all IDEs. I use Vim and it completes strings as good as it completes symbols so no difference here.

EDIT:

If your order was ASC then you could use `MyModel.order(:title).all` which is definitely better than `MyModel.order("title").all`

Comment: I agree completely with you that the "title DESC" approach is better here but i don't really like both of them. i am looking for something different. is there? or should "title DESC" should be sufficient?

Comment: I think "title DESC" is sufficient here. I edited my answer with an alternative in case you want to order by ASC order.